# chatting recyclerview's type2 don't display

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

[i want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Hsk.png)

left display is Data class and view type ==0

right display is MeData class and view type ==2

Currently I would like to use two multiview types using recyclerview.

Data and MeData are two types class.

If return value of getItemViewType (int position) is 0, ui for data class works normally, but if return value 2, Me data class does not work and error occurs.

+

There is one function defined differently for the two view types, which does not define the `getItemCount` function for MeData.

```
private ArrayList<Data> Data = new ArrayList<Data>();
private ArrayList<MeData> MeData = new ArrayList<MeData>();

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if(viewType == 0) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatitem, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder0(view);   
        }
        else{
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatitem2, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder2(view); 
        }

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
    // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
    //return position 0; <- not error
    return position % 2 * 2; <- error
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(holder.getItemViewType() == 0){
        ((ViewHolder0) holder).onBind(Data.get(position));

    }
    else{
        ((ViewHolder2) holder).onBind(MeData.get(position));
    }

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Data.size();
}




void addItem(Data data) {

    Data.add(data);
}

void addItem(MeData data) {
    MeData.add(data);
}
```

Why does an error occur if the return value of `getItemViewType` is 2? And how do we solve it?

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: i use realtime-firebase and javacode